# XYZ da Vinci 3D printer doesn't want to load filament

Tags: xyz-da-vinci-mini-w

My XYZ da Vinci 3D printer doesn't want to load my spool but I still have a lot of filament on it. I took the chip out in both spool and the printer itself and made sure I loaded them in correctly, but it still says that the spool is empty and I don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 2):

### Proprietary systems have proprietary problems

The XYZ daVinci series is locked down in a way that without both an RFID and the sensor, it does not and can not recognize a spool at all, and thus does not print.

Resetting a spool's chip, according to the manufacturer, risks frying the motherboard.

However, DaVinci offers a [special spool holder](https://www.xyzprinting.com/eshop/en-US/product/OpenSmartTag) to solve the issue.

Comment: Oh god. And it's $49.99 and out of stock. Absolutely disgusting.